# Refresh token response with missing elements of conversation object

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have been working with Direct Line for a long time, but I'm confused when refreshing tokens. I send a request like:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/refresh' --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxx'
```

And according to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#refresh-token), it should return a `conversation` object (described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#conversation-object)), that should contain (amongs others) `streamUrl` and `referenceGrammarId` (as it does in [generate token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#generate-token)), but I don't get them in the response, I get just `conversationId`, `token` and `expires_in`, making it more difficult to handle the token refresh.

Is this the expected behavior, or those missing properties should be present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was the expected behavior, said the technical team at Microsoft.